# How to know if add_custom_command's post_build flavour succeeded?

Tags: cmake

I want to run a few checks on a binary after it's been created, so `add_custom_command()` and the POST_BUILD flavor of it looked appealing in the sense that it, well, runs post build. But how do I check the exit code of said command?

I was saddened to see that only `execute_process()` has a RESULT_VARIABLE. The "normal" `add_custom_command()` has an OUTPUT variable in file format that I guess you can write to, even though that seems ridiculously cumbersome just to get the exit code. But the POST_BUILD version of the `add_custom_command()` seemingly has nothing.

I have seen some cases where people are doing stuff like `COMMAND my_command >> ${RESULT_FILE}`, but is that all there is?

Comment: The exit code should be checked by the build system by itself. If your `add_custom_command` generates actual output, consider it adding a  real command, not a s a `POST_BUILD`. What for and how would you use the return value from `add_custom_command`? If it fails, it's equivalent to failing to build  the actual targets fails.

Comment: Thanks, no this would essentially just be a check for whether a certain string is present, so I just want to either pass or fail the build depending on this condition. I.e. I want to run a command, store it's exit code and then do FATAL_ERROR unless it's what I expect.

Comment: But there is no cmake there. There is no FATAL_ERROR. On build stage no cmake is involved. So just check if, write a short program/script that would check the string. Along `COMMAND python3 script.py` and inside `script.py` write a python script that would execute the command and check exit status using python tools. You can also execute a cmake script, if you want to.

Comment: I see, thanks! On a side note it just seems like it'd been nice if there had been support for doing that kind of stuff rather than writing additional scripts. Eg I see a lot of using POST_BUILD to say create symlinks but then there is no check to ensure that this symlinking worked, unless you wrap it all in a script and die from within it. Thanks again!

Comment: The build systems checks all commands, no checks are needed, they are already there. Simply speaking (on a unix system with makefile generator) cmake takes all build commands and creates a long `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && ...` line for build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I.e. I want to run a command, store it's exit code and then do FATAL_ERROR unless it's what I expect

You can execute any program to do that. So choose your favorite programming language of choice and write a program that will do just that. Then execute that program during build stage post your target build. The build system should pick the exit status of the program and fail the build. One could use cmake as a programming language to write, for example:

```
# your_script.cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
execute_process(COMMAND a_command RESULT_VARIABLE res)
if (NOT res STREQUAL "0")
     message(FATAL_ERROR "")
endif()
```

Then execute that script with cmake as an interpreter during build:

```
add_some_target_like_library_or_executable_or_custom_target(target  ....)
add_custom_command(POST_BUILD target 
     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P path/to/your_script.cmake
)
```